# event trigger problem with function.bind()

Tags: javascript

Good afternoon everybody, i have  issues to activate this function:
 `function clickMe(){return this.color="red"}`,inside of an object.
it should be triggered by button, here the code:

```
script>
    var btn = document.querySelector("#btn");
    var txt = document.querySelector("#txt");
    btn.addEventListener("click",activeNewColor)
    
    var objCss ={fontsize:"40px",
              color:"pink",
            click: function clickMe(){return this.color="red"}
            }
    let colorRed=objCss.click.bind(objCss);
    
    var activeNewColor= () =>{

        return colorRed()
        }

    //activeNewColor()

    Object.assign(txt.style, objCss); 
</script>
```

Comment: Such a strange code... What do you want to achieve? If you click the button, then `#btn` and `#txt` should change color to red? Or only button? Or only text?

Comment: yes sorry for the mess, only the #txt...

Comment: Why not do this ---> `btn.addEventListener('click', () => txt.style.color = 'red');`? What you are trying to do can be done with three lines of code.

Comment: Why not use the javascript library or jQuery plugin and just used the predefined functions instead of your functions? You can define functions within the event listeners

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```js
function buttonClicked() {
  const txt = document.getElementById('txt');
  txt.style.color = 'red';
}
```

```css
button {
  color: green;
}

textarea {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  font-size: 40px;
  color: pink;
}
```

```html
<div><button id="btn" onclick="buttonClicked()">Click me</button></div>
<textarea id="txt">Example text</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can attribute style with different classes and use `classList.toggle` to remove/add a class from an element, like this :

```js
var txt = document.querySelector("#txt");

function changeColor() {
  txt.classList.toggle('pink');
  txt.classList.toggle('red');
}
```

```css
#txt {
  font-size: 14px;
}

#txt.pink {
  color: pink;
}
  
#txt.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn" onclick="changeColor()">Change text color</button>
<span id="txt" class="pink">text</span>
```